# O365 Excel Help - Copy Cell Sum based on dynamic range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Turning to you folks for help. Here's the ask:

In Excel, without using a Pivot Table, I need to:

Sum all cells in column L on Tab1 to Cell B58 of Tab2 based on a two criteria match:

Criteria 1: Workers Name (Tab2, Cell B2) matches any cell on Tab1 column H
Criteria 2: Job Type (Tab2 Cell A58) matches any cell on Tab1 column E.

If both criteria are met (i.e. Joe Smith worked 10 Installation jobs so the criteria meet on 10 different lines), I need the sum of all cells in column L for Joe Smith and Installations to go into Tab2, Cell B58.

Yes, that's a crazy ask I'm sure, but this one is beyond me.

I do understand that Pivot Tables are easier, but this spreadsheet has a need for dynamic updates based on simple cut and paste onto other tabs. I have to keep this simple for everyone.

Your help or direction would be GREATLY appreciated, and if you need anything from me, please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like [`SUMIFS()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: I've tried several iterations to no avail. I had also toyed with Index/match and sumifs, but this one is a bit of a headache.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the SUMIFS your tried.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your need it is for something like this...

[image]

SUMIFS() does the job. If you are doing this from one tab to another then you need to make sure the cross-tab references are correct.